# POM for 'log4j:log4j:pom:1.2.15:compile' is invalid

Tags: maven, maven-2, log4j

Can please anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here ?

I am getting the following warnings when I run mvn install:

```
[WARNING] POM for 'log4j:log4j:pom:1.2.15:compile' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Cannot read project model from interpolating filter of serialized version. for project log4j:log4j at Artifact [log4j:log4j:pom:1.2.15:compile]
[WARNING] POM for 'log4j:log4j:pom:1.2.15:compile' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Cannot read project model from interpolating filter of serialized version. for project log4j:log4j at Artifact [log4j:log4j:pom:1.2.15:compile]
```

Pom file has:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with your dependency declaration. Therefore, I would guess something went wrong during the download of the POM.

Delete the relevant folder in your local repository (e.g. `.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.15`) and try again.